# Tag for the venous system

Tags: discussion, tags

At the moment, Medical Sciences SE has tag [vein-venous](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vein-venous) without any synonyms.

I propose that the tag be renamed [venous-system](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/venous-system) with synonym [vein](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vein) or [veins](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/veins).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implemented as suggested in the question.